# htaccess Silent Redirect to Subdirectory: Subdirectory showing when no trailing '/'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have dug high and low around Google and StackOverflow to try and figure out my problem, trying countless solutions but nothing has completely worked.

I'm looking to move the web root of the main domain on my server to a sub-directory.  What I have currently for a server path to my web root:

```
/home/user/public_html/MyWebFilesHere
```

What I'm looking to have:

```
/home/user/public_html/subdir/MyWebfilesHere
```

When I browse to mydomain.com, there should be no visible difference though (i.e. "subdir" not visible after redirect).

Unfortunately, I am restricted to doing this purely with a .htaccess file since I'm on shared hosting and don't have access to Apache config files and such. :(

What I currently have in my .htaccess in public_html is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```

This successfully redirects all queries to the sub-directory, however there's a really weird issue.  If I go to

```
mydomain.com/Contact/
```

it works great, redirecting the query to the path /subdir/Contact/ but leaving the address bar alone.  If I go to

```
mydomain.com/Contact
```

(Note the lack of a trailing '/') though, what shows in the address bar is

```
mydomain.com/subdir/Contact/
```

which isn't what I want since "subdir" is showing.

For a working example on my actual site, try browsing to

```
colincwilliams.com/Contact/
```

compared with

```
colincwilliams.com/Contact
```

Do you guys have any ideas on how to make this work silently both with and without a trailing slash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably happening because mod_dir (the module that automatically redirects the browser if a request for a directory is missing a trailing slash to the same thing *with* a trailing slash. See the [DirectorySlash directive in mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)

What's happening is:

1. You request: `mydomain.com/Contact`
2. mod_dir doesn't touch this since `/Contact` isn't a directory
3. `/Contact` gets rewritten to `/subdir/Contact` and *internally* redirected
4. mod_dir sees that `/subdir/Contact` is a directory and missing the trailing slash so it *redirects the browser* to `mydomain.com/subdir/Contact/`
5. So now, your browser's location bar has the /subdir/ in it.

You can add `DirectorySlash off` in your .htaccess to turn off mod_dir from redirecting. But if you want directories to have trailing slashes, you can add a separate condition for it. Based on what you already have, we can expand it to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Has a trailing slash, don't append one when rewriting
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ./\ HTTP/1\.[01]$ [OR]
# OR if it's a file that ends with one of these extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|html?|jpg|gif|css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]

# Missing trailing slash, append one
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [^/]\ HTTP/1\.[01]$
# But only if it's not a file that ends with one of these extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1/ [L]
```

Note: I changed `!^/mydomain/` to `!^/subdir/`, figured it was a typo because without it, mod_rewrite would loop internally indefinitely (foo -> /subdir/foo -> /subdir/subdir/foo -> /subdir/subdir/subdir/foo, etc). If I got that wrong, you can change it back.

Edit: See my additions of RewriteCond's matching against `\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|css)`. These are the file extensions that get passed through without getting trailing slashes added. You can add/remove to suit your needs.

Comment: Jon Lin, your answer was super helpful and made a ton of sense.  Thanks!  It did work (the second suggestion adding the trailing slash), except it has now broken my CSS links for some reason.  They are formatted as "/CSS/core-style.css" but are returning a 404.

Comment: After a touch of investigation, it appears the CSS links are bypassing the htaccess file; "/CSS/..." is looking directly in the public_html directory for CSS/ rather than going into subdir.

Comment: Oh, forgot you need to exclude files from the trailing "/" stuff. See my edit

Comment: That worked beautifully!  Thanks so much!! :D  Only one minor change I had to make: Your new statement should only be on the "missing trailing slash" portion, not the "has trailing slash" portion.  If it's on the latter as well, the same issue occurs with the CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Lin's answer was very helpful in determining what was causing the problem in my very similar setup. For completeness I will include the relevant information from his answer:

> This is probably happening because mod_dir (the module that automatically redirects the browser if a request for a directory is missing a trailing slash to the same thing with a trailing slash. See the [DirectorySlash directive in mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)
>
> What's happening is:
>
> 1. You request: `mydomain.com/Contact`
> 2. mod_dir doesn't touch this since `/Contact` isn't a directory
> 3. `/Contact` gets rewritten to `/subdir/Contact` and internally redirected
> 4. mod_dir sees that `/subdir/Contact` is a directory and missing the trailing slash so it redirects the browser to `mydomain.com/subdir/Contact/`
> 5. So now, your browser's location bar has the /subdir/ in it.

In my case, I had requests being redirected to `/subdir` with a few exceptions and didn't want to have to re-enable DirectorySlash for each of those exceptions.

By allowing RewriteEngine to continue after the initial redirect to `/subdir`, it's possible to mimic what mod_dir would be doing while also taking `/subdir` into account, before mod_dir gets to see it.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception1|exception2|...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*) $1/ [R,L]
```

Note: You may need to be careful about allowing RewriteEngine to continue if there are further rules. Not matching the second rule will continue on to any further rules which may produce a different result.

This can be avoided by using a third rule to stop RewriteEngine processing if the redirect into `/subdir` has happened:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^subdir
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```