# Redirecting using Rewriterule from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a domain (let's say www.example.com) and would like this to point to /Example_folder/ of my server (within /var/www/).

So, if I try to goto www.example.com/images/test.html or example.com/images/test.html, it should be actually pointing at /Example_folder/images/test.html.

I tried to get this working using following code, but I can't figure out.

Trial#1:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*) /Example_Folder/ [L]
```

If I use above code, I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*) /Example_Folder/index.html [L]
```

If I use above code (where index.html is specified), it would redirect but I can't get my domain to point at its subdirectories. (www.example.com/images/test.html would also point at www.example.com/index.html)

I got it working using the code from link below:
[htaccess Silent Redirect to Subdirectory: Subdirectory showing when no trailing '/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046222/htaccess-silent-redirect-to-subdirectory-subdirectory-showing-when-no-trailing)

Last thing that remains is that when I point to www.example.com/Example_Folder, I want the address bar to show www.example.com, but I have not figure that out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based rule to avoid rewrite loop:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^((?!Example_Folder/).+)$ /Example_Folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Which means rewrite only if URI doesn't already start with `Example_Folder/`.

Comment: Actuallly, I'm still having a problem. Now with negative lookahead, I'm not getting rewrite loop, but when I try to point to subdirectories (eg: www.example.com/images) the address bar changes to www.example.com/Example_Folder/images. Are there anyways I could hide "Example_Folder" from address bar?

Comment: One thing that is weird is that, if I'm pointing to the file in subdirectory (eg: www.example.com/images/index.html), it works fine, but if I point it to just subdirectory, the address bar includes "Example_Folder"

Comment: Hmm weird as above rule is not doing any redirect. Try placing `DirectorySlash Off` on top of your .htaccess

Comment: DirectorySlash off did the trick for hiding "Example_Folder" to appear on address bar, but the new problem is due to directoryslash off, I can only access subdirectories with www.example.com/images/ and not www.example.com/images

Comment: Also another thing is, when I type www.example.com/Example_Folder, I can actually access it (It's pointing to Example_Folder). Aren't I suppose to get Forbidden instead as it should be pointing www.example.com/Example_Folder/Example_Folder?